# Checking if button has a specific attribute does not work in jQuery

Tags: jquery, attributes

I have this code:

```
<body>
  <button class="test" aria-label="This is a button">
    <span>test</span>
  </button>

  <button class="test2" aria-label="This is a second button">
    <span>test2</span>
  </button>
</body>
```

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 if( $("button").attr("aria-label") ) {
     $(this).find("span").attr("aria-hidden", "true");
  }
});
```

I want to add **aria-hidden** to **true** to all **span** elements if it's parent (button) has attribute **aria-label**.

I tried chaning my code to something like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 if( $("button").attr("aria-label") ) {
     $("span", this).attr("aria-hidden", "true");
  }
});
```

AND

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 if( $("button").getAttribute("aria-label") ) {
     $("span", this).attr("aria-hidden", "true");
  }
});
```

but it's not working.

Comment: Add html to your code to reproduce it.

Comment: I've addedd HTML code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve using **has** function to check for particular attribute in the element as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if($("button").has("aria-label")) {
        $(this).find("span").attr("aria-hidden", "true");
    }
});
```

To achieve above functionality with all buttons as follows:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button.test').each(function() {
        if($(this).attr("aria-label")) {
            $(this).find("span").attr("aria-hidden", "true");
        } else {
            alert('Something wrong');
        } 
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<div>
        <h1>Test this Task</h1>
        <button class="test" aria-label="This is a button">
            <span>test</span>
          </button>
        
          <button class="test" aria-label="This is a second button">
            <span>test2</span>
          </button>
    </div>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-o88AwQnZB+VDvE9tvIXrMQaPlFFSUTR+nldQm1LuPXQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I tried but I need minimum 15 reputation to do that. Sorry.
Edit: I've permuted up-vote and accept. I've accepted your answer.

Thanks again!

Comment: One question. Does using 'each' makes code better or what? The code I'm using with .has() works fine. I just want to learn the difference. Thanks.

Comment: As I can see you are trying to achieve same thing with both buttons and span tags, So, its better to assign same class and code the way did which will avoid code redundancy and enhance the code readability.